# Does anyone know origins of 万一?

Tags: etymology

Does anyone knows how 万一 became a phrase with "just in case" meaning?
Is it a shorthand of a longer phrase or chengyu?

Comment: It may help to consider that English has similar numerical/probability phrases: "in the thousand-to-one chance that ..."; "in the off-chance that ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://baike.baidu.com/subview/199191/8163691.htm gives a plausible answer: it refers to a remote possibility of a thing X happening.  Sort of "among the ten thousand and one things that could happen, one is X."  Far back in ancient and classical Chinese,  the ten thousand things are a proverbial way to express all that happens in this world.  But I did not find sources giving any specific classical source for 万一 meaning "just in case."

Comment: looks like true. "In case (most unprobable) you die." 万一你死.

Comment: A further support for the answer would be the saying 不怕一萬，祇怕萬一 

The ten thousand (regular scenarios) don't bother me; I only worry about the one in ten thousand (unlikely scenario).